# how do I sum a column with times that are related to another colums

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet with names, that appear up to 20-30 times in the column. Every name has in another column a time related, meaning workhours. The times are in the format hh:mm:ss (e.g. 01:15:00). I want to sum those hours, for every name particularly. SO every person called "John", has worked 100 hours - for example.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be too complex a task. Here's one tip before my solution: Searching through the Excel helpfile and/or function list often rewards you with ideas to try yourself - thus enhancing your own Excel know how.

To your problem/task: you'll need to employ a so called SUMIF-function (basically combining a SUM-function with the possibility to check for other "criteria"). Here's what you need to do:

[image]

Hope this works fine for you!
Best
Michael

Comment: ok, but my column B contains times, such as 03:13:27, like this

Comment: There are already lots of solutions on the internet and MS website and you can find it with a simple google search http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/add-times-HP003056109.aspx http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/add-or-subtract-units-of-time-HP010070466.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506625/excel-add-one-hour

Comment: @ Miha: It doesn't matter if you want to sum up regular numbers or times. You need to set the cell-format of the cell containing the SUMIF-function to "TIME" and you should be fine. Again try the Excel helpfile for "SUMIF".

Comment: Thank you Michael but I've tride that too, and it does not work

Comment: @ Miha: As Lưu Vĩnh Phúc already put it we will certainly need more info and/or examples what it is that you're trying to do and HOW you are trying to do it. Maybe you could upload a small example (picture) of your spreadsheet and the used formula?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the sumif command [described here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx). In the criteria argument use the name.

The command would be something like

```
SUMIF(A1:A10,"john",B1:10)
```

where your names are listed in column A and your hours are listed in column B.

That should do exactly what you want.

If the hours are listed in a time format, you should convert them to minutes before summing them using the int function described [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/convert-times-HP003056110.aspx).

In column C use the command

```
B1-Int(B1)
```

copied down along the column.

Then do you sum using the commands
    SUMIF(A1:A10,"john",C1:10)

Comment: ok, but my column B contains times, such as 03:13:27, like this.

Comment: There's no problem summing the time. Actually it's just numbers under the hood

Comment: OK, BUT IT DOESNT WORK. MY RESULT IS 00

Comment: then you should add more information to the question, what you have tried,... not asking a new one.

Comment: SORY I DIDNT KNEW HOW THIS  WORKS. I AM NEW. SO I TRIED THIS FORMULAS AND IT DOES NOT WORK

Comment: MY COLUMNS WITH HOURS DONT EVEN SUM, IF I WANT SUM FOR EXAMPLE B1:B10 RESULT ALSO 00:00

Comment: So can you help? do you know why this error?

Comment: I hope that helps. Update your question to specify the format of the time.

Comment: @Miha did that help then?